# resize cell.UIImageView.image

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i have the different image with the different size too, i want to put it in cell.imageView.image in every cell, but i want make same size in every cell although the image have the different size, i write this on my code :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    cell.imageView.image = image;
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

    float sw=image.size.width/cell.imageView.image.size.width;
    float sh=image.size.height/cell.imageView.image.size.height;
    cell.imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(sw, sh);
```

but it doesn't work, i'am sure that's right..
any body can help me.??[image]

Comment: iam sorry guys iam newbie, so i dont understand about the rule.
so How Can i accept the answers .??
sorry for this freak questions..

Comment: @Imam: you just accepted my answer:). Now, you know how

Comment: hha thnx guys,, it's so ridiculous..

Comment: that's ok man, it is not your fault. Many people don't know like you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cell is a built in cell, it is supposed that the cell will resize all the images to a fixed, default size. Can you post an screenshot of your application as well?

Comment: pardon me, u mean the UITableViewCell screenshot.??

Comment: yeah, I want the application screenshot. Because all images in table cell should be at the same size

Comment: you can edit your question, there is an image button there (with an "image" icon), click on that to upload from your computer

Comment: i've uploaded my screenshoot..
hope it can be useful..
thnx before guys

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem. In this case, you should try to create your own UITableViewCell. Here is a blog post about that http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/06/28/custom-uitableviewcell-from-a-xib-in-interface-builder/ And after you create UITableViewCell, you can drag a UIImageView with fixed size into

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this same problem.  I wanted the photos to be 65 x 65, but they were filling in the size of the UITableViewCell instead.  I resolved it by creating the UIImageView programmatically and adding it as a subview to the UITableViewCell. For example:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:photo];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(6.5, 6.5, 65., 65.);
[cell addSubview:imageView];
```

Edit for clarity: This problem was occurring when I tried to create the UIImageView in Interface Builder.  I took it out of Interface Builder and added it programmatically instead.

Comment: this seems to cover the text with the image. any ideas on how to shift the text over as well?

Comment: I actually created a custom XIB file for my UITableViewCell, so I created the text to be out of the way of my picture.  Basically, you're going to have to create a custom view (UITableViewCell subclass), programmatically or with Interface Builder.  You might want to search for custom UITableViewCell to find some implementations because it is a bit too much to put into a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else runs into this with custom cells: it appears that if your custom cell has an outlet named `imageView`, it will be treated like the image view in a basic-style cell, i.e. the image view's size will be adjusted. Simply picking another name avoids this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I just saw your question. I faced the same problem, and the code worked for me is following:

`cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);`

Hope, it will solve your problem