# Stop TableView cell UIImage resizing in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, resize, tableview

I have a standard (i.e. not a custom) TableView cell with text and images, the problem is my images are different sizes and I want to put them in as something like UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill.  I simply want the UIImage to be 54x54 and not resizes all the time - I just want them square!

There are lots of ideas out there but none of them work, the closest I came worked BUT the image was on top of the text (it added another image as a subview).

I am not keen on using a custom cell as I use edit mode to drag stuff about and I have not figured that out yet with custom cells.

EDIT

I latest I have tried;

```
UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(54, 54);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[tempImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
cell.imageView.image = scaledImage;
```

I have this in the cellForRow which I hoped would do it;

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

This only works on custom cells;

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,54,54);
}
```

This works well but it covers the text;

```
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 54)];
imgView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[imgView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[imgView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
```

This shows the exact problem I am having;

[Stackoverflow problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553331/resize-cell-uiimageview-image)

ANOTHER EDIT

okay this worked, thanks;

```
[cell setIndentationWidth:54];
[cell setIndentationLevel:1];

UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 54)];
imgView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[imgView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[imgView setImage:myImages[indexPath.row]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: What other options did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to subclass UITableViewCell and create your own custom cell :D

but, anyway... try by adding this

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

UIImageView *imgView = nil;
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 54)];
    imgView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imgView.tag = 123;

    [cell.contentView insertSubview:imgView atIndex:0];
    [cell setIndentationWidth:54];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:1];
}
else
{
    imgView = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:123];
}
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
```

Comment: The key was the setIndentation..... which enabled me to to use another method which obscured the text.

Comment: And just for clarity you MUST setMasksToBounds or it does not work.